# Spyne: Why am I getting empty responses for json requests?

Tags: python, json, django, rpc, spyne

I have a working application that accepts SOAP requests, processes the requests, forwards the SOAP request to an API, processes the response, and then forwards the response to the client.

I'm trying to change this application so that it will be JSON between my application and the client but still use SOAP between API and my application

Now, it can successfully accept JSON requests from client and send/receive SOAP with API. However, all the responses to client are empty.

The only case that I receive a non-empty response is when there are validation errors with my JSON request.

Here are some code that might be relevant

```
app = Application([MyServer],
              MY_NAMESPACE,
              in_protocol=JsonDocument(validator='soft'),
              out_protocol=JsonDocument())

application_server = csrf_exempt(MyDjangoApplication(app))
```

definition of MyDjangoApplication

```
class MyDjangoApplication(DjangoApplication):
def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    retval = self.HttpResponseObject()

    def start_response(status, headers):
        # Status is one of spyne.const.http
        status, reason = status.split(' ', 1)

        retval.status_code = int(status)
        for header, value in headers:
            retval[header] = value

    environ = request.META.copy()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = self.handle_rpc(environ, start_response)
    else:
        home_path = reverse('proxy:list_method')

        uri = MY_ENDPOINT_URL or request.build_absolute_uri(home_path)

        # to generate wsdl content
        response = self._WsgiApplication__handle_wsdl_request(environ, start_response, uri)

        if request.path == home_path and _is_wsdl_request(environ):
            fn = None
        elif 'method_name' in kwargs:
            fn = view_method
        else:
            fn = list_method

        if fn:
            return fn(request, app=self, *args, **kwargs)

    self.set_response(retval, response)

    return retval
```

Definition of MyServer

```
class MyServer(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(MyTestMethodRequest, Sign, **method(_returns=MyTestMethodResponse))
    @check_method()
    def TestMethod(ctx, request, signature):
        response = {
            'Data': "test"
        }
        return response
```

Definitions of MyTestMethodRequest, MyTestMethodResponse:

```
class MyTestMethodRequest(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    MyString = String(encoding=STR_ENCODING)


class MyTestMethodResponse(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    Data = String(encoding=STR_ENCODING)
```

Definition of check_method:

```
def check_method(error_handler=None):
    def _check_method(func):
        method_name = func.__name__

        def __check_method(ctx, request, signature, *args, **kwargs):
            if hasattr(request, '__dict__'):
                request = request.__dict__

            if hasattr(signature, '__dict__'):
                signature = signature.__dict__

            response = func(ctx, request or {}, signature or {}, *args, **kwargs)

            # setting output protocol
            output_message = generate_out_string(ctx, [response])

            return response

        __check_method.__name__ = method_name
        __check_method.__doc__ = func.__doc__

        return __check_method

    return _check_method
```

Definition of generate_out_string:

```
def generate_out_string(ctx, objects):
    ctx.out_protocol = ctx.in_protocol

    return _generate_out_string(ctx, objects)

def _generate_out_string(ctx, objects):
    protocol = ctx.out_protocol

    ctx.out_object = objects

    protocol.serialize(ctx, protocol.RESPONSE)
    protocol.create_out_string(ctx)

    out_string = list(ctx.out_string)

    return out_string[0] if out_string else ''
```

Note: Most of these definitions have been simplified (I have removed lines which I think are not relevant)

Comment: Does it work when you use plain DjangoApplication? What's wrong with it anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using the default DjangoApplication yields the same result. I don't know the full details as to why a custom DjangoApplication is used but I suppose the main reason for it is so that it will only process the request if it's 'POST', otherwise it will display a custom page.

Comment: Ok, please post services code since your DjangoApplication subclass is irrelevant here and Application instantiation looks just fine.

Comment: If it's a bug I'll fix it, if not I'll tell you how to fix it but first I have to reproduce it.

Comment: updated. not sure if these are the codes that you need.

Comment: replacing `output_message = generate_out_string(ctx, [response])` with `output_message = response` seems to have fixed the problem. But I don't understand how it's fixed and why it was needed in the first place.

Comment: Wow, there's half a Spyne in there :) When you're messing so much with private apis, you can't expect everything to work now can you :)

Comment: May I ask, why these were needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, I can't say I understand what good all those additional decorators and modifiers around arguments do.

Removing them should fix all of your problems.

So let:

```
class MyTestMethodRequest(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    MyString = Unicode


class MyTestMethodResponse(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MY_NAMESPACE

    Data = Unicode
```

Assuming you have the following service:

```
class MyService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(MyTestMethodRequest, Sign, _returns=MyTestMethodResponse)
    def TestMethod(ctx, request, signature):
        return MyTestMethodResponse(data="test")
```

You can have:

```
app_json = Application([MyService],
              MY_NAMESPACE,
              in_protocol=JsonDocument(validator='soft'),
              out_protocol=JsonDocument())
```

and

```
app_soap = Application([MyService],
              MY_NAMESPACE,
              in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
              out_protocol=Soap11())
```

which in turn you can pass to `DjangoApplication` as usual.:

```
app_json_dja = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(app_json))

app_soap_dja = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(app_soap))
```

which in turn you can mount in Django's url router.

I hope this helps!